# How to get the Office 365 group picture along with group properties

Tags: development, office-365, microsoft-graph

I am able to retrieve all the required properties for all the group. To get the group image I have created another method. I am calling this method inside above all groups loop. Of course I am getting output and show the group name along with Image, but it is taking close to 20-25 secs since getGroupImage method is calling inside all groups loop.
My actual question is how to get the group image along with the group properties. If I see in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_get) there is no property mentioned about group image. How to get the group properties along with image in single call?
This is how i am getting group pictures

```
public async Task<List<GroupPic>> GetGroupPhotos(string accessToken,string[] groupIds) {
            List<GroupPic> pics = new List<GroupPic>();
            foreach (var groupId in groupIds)
            {
                var k = await GetGroupPicture(accessToken, groupId);
                pics.Add(new GroupPic { groupPic = k, groupId = groupId });
            }
            return pics;
        }
```

here for `groupIds` parameter I am passing all groupIds at once and looping them (this is slightly different than above I have mentioned).
I am calling this method once I get the group details. So user will first see group details after few seconds pictures will get loaded.

Comment: can you share a code snippet of this ? How you are getting a group and the photo of it ?

Comment: See my edited question